# Using cloud-init and creating variables to use

Tags: linux, azure, cloud-init

I am having some issues with cloud-init and trying to get some variables set so that I can call them later in the cloud-init script.  I can get curl xyz to work outside of setting any variables...let me explain:

If I have this line in my runcmd: section it runs just fine:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

However, If I try this command it will fail on the :

```
token=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net -H "metadata:true |jq --raw-output '.access_token')
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to get the token line to work... but all have failed.  I thought to put the whole line in ' ', [ ], etc...but still no luck.

I am currently getting errors like:

```
found unexpected ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 48, column 24:
      - [token=$(curl "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/iden ...
```

so I am not sure what the difference is between the lines that will work (top curl) and the one that fails...minus setting the variable part token=$(...)

Comment: Hmmm not sure how to edit my post... but the command that is failing is really this:

token=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net -H "metadata:true |jq --raw-output '.access_token')

Comment: Looking more closely I am seeing that the cloud-init-output.log shows:

/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd: 13: /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd: curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net: not found

However, in the /var/lib/instance/scripts/runcmd file it shows:

token=$('curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=source=https://vault.azure.net' -H metadata:true |jq --raw-output '.access_token')

So why is it dropping the -H part?

Thoughts...

Comment: There is an `edit` button at the bottom of your post. Please use that rather than posting new information in comments, which make it hard to follow your question.

Comment: How do you use cloud-init to create the variable? Can you share the cloud-init context?